# Adding SSL parameters to pepper_box config in jmeter

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, jmeter

I'm trying to test a kafka stream on jmeter using the pepper box config, but each time I try adding java request parameters it goes back to the default parameters without saving the ones I have added.  I have tried the recommendations on here of adding the underscore, so `_ssl.enabled`, but the params are still disappearing.  Any recommendations? Using jmeter5.3 and pepper-box1.0

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put your SSL properties to the [PepperBoxKafkaSampler](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#pepperboxkafkasampler) directly, there are pre-populated placeholders which you can change and the changes persist.

[image]

The same behaviour is for [Java Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request_Defaults)

It might be the case your installation got corrupt somehow or there is a conflict with another [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/), check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

In the meantime you may find [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) article useful

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I got around this issue by cloning the pepperbox repository https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box and made changes to the PepperBoxKafkaSampler.java file, updated the setupTest() method with your props. You can also add the parameters making use of the .addArgument() method (used in PepperBoxKafkaSampler.java) to make the parameters available in jmeter.

Rebuild the repo using maven `mvn clean install` replace the old pepperbox jar in jmeter/lib/ext with your new built jar.